# Is it safe to use dynamic-imported components in vue with laravel-mix

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I tried dynamic importing of vue components to increase performance of my app by loading components async and only when needed, as yu can see in the links bellow I had lots of problems with trying to get this to work, so I decided to ditch the idea, now I'm wondering if thave there been any news about this?

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/elixir/laravel-mix-dynamic-imports

https://laravel-mix.com/docs/5.0/upgrade

laravel and vue are used a lot so it's rare to see such a crazy bug hasn't been fixed yet.

Comment: The bug is actually on Webpack and it should be fixed in 5.0

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use it with laravel mix this bug was before v4 and they fixed it and every thing is working as a charm